# String `matches` does not appear to work in a JSR223 Assertion

Tags: java, jmeter

I have the following assertion code...

```
Boolean result = prev.getResponseDataAsString().matches(".*Close.*")
System.out.println(result)
if(!result){
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try{
        writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("I:\\failedpayload.txt"))
          writer.write(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
     }
     catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage())
     }
     finally{
        writer.close()
     }
    // System.out.println("Response:"+prev.getResponseDataAsString());
}
AssertionResult.setFailure(!result);
```

The test fails and result ends up being false. However, when I look at the file that gets created I see the search string there.

Why `Close` in the file that is created but not when creating the boolean?

Comment: What is the effective content of the file?

Comment: I am guessing that your string contains multiple lines, but `.` in regex by default can't match line separator which prevents `matches` to work since it checks if regex matches *entire* string. But anyway `matches(".*Close.*")` should probably be rewritten as `contains("Close")`.

Comment: Contains was failing sometimes too. I never debugged why but that was why I switched to Matches. Added some more info on why I am not using contains

Comment: In this case if `matches` will work `contains` will also work so using `matches` is not any improvement. See for what case it fails and then we can start helping you. Otherwise we will only rely on guessing which is not very efficient way of solving problems.

Comment: Like I said it fails randomly but the output in the console shows the value it is using in the contains. See update

Comment: I will try to upload some of the output I am seeing.

Comment: @Pshemo there is the data

Answer (score 1):

This did end up working...

```
import java.util.regex.*
...
Pattern aPattern = Pattern.compile(".*Close.*",Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher aMatcher = aPattern.matcher(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
Boolean result = aMatcher.find();
```

Basically as the comments suggested matches doesn't work for multiline.

Comment: Since you are using `aMatcher.find();` there is no need to use `.*` part in pattern which means you also don't need `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag.

Comment: Anyway it is very hard for me to believe that `matches` would work in cases where `contains` would fail. There must be another problem hidden in your code but to solve it we would need to see [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Comment: Unfortunately given how complex the environment is I am not sure I will be able to create one of those. I can publish my code and how it affects things but I can't really publish an simple example.

Comment: @Pshemo Could it be that the JSR223 Assertion isn't threadsafe?

Comment: @Pshemo I have removed the extra I added and I will just create another JIRA. Keep on the lookout!

Comment: Sorry, I will not be able to help you today. Will try to visit this question tomorrow to see if I will be able to reproduce problem which you ware facing (without it it will be hard to debug anything).

Comment: No prob thanks for your help. However, it is running contains on a rather large webpage with tons of weird chars in a JMeter env with lots of threads and it only happens intermittently. I think another question would be better than confusing this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Groovy - you can use [match operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_match_operator) like:

```
def text = 'I Was Close Enough' 
def matcher = (text ==~ /.*Close.*/)
log.info('Matches: ' + matcher)
```

[image: JMeter GRoovy Matches]

If you want multiline - you can use `(?m)` operator, in Groovy it treats the input as multiline:

[image: JMeter Groovy Regex]

More information:

- [Matcher (Groovy JDK Enhancements)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)
- [Groovy Goodness: Matchers for Regular Expressions](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: I still can't figure out why it can't find it when I do contains in a request assertion (that is why I am using JSR anyway) I know the XML doesn't pass validation because of some &NBSP; s. But I don't understand why that affects the text response.